# Twilio Device.connect() results in "Bad JSON in msg"

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

Our React app sends a GET request to our API requesting a Twilio token. Out API then requests the token from Twilio. The token is then sent in the response back to the React app. The React app then executes `Twilio.Device.setup(token, {debug: true})`, and this appears to happen successfully.

The `Twilio.Device.instance` object appears to have the token retrieved from the server, and the token matches what the server responded with AND what the server prints to the logs.

We then call `Twilio.Device.connect()` which results in an error message to the console :

`{"payload":{"callsid":"<SOME_ID>","error":{"code":31100,"message":"Bad JSON in msg"}},"type":"hangup","version":""}`

Opening the Dev console I see this is all happening in a web socket connection, and the payload sent RIGHT before this message appears (and it is reliably sent immediately before the response, so I believe it is what triggers the error) is a payload of this form:

```
{
    "type":"invite",
    "version":"1.4",
    "payload":{
        "sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 436124720934282410 2 IN ... A BUNCH OF DATA WITH CARRIAGE RETURNS ... f-d0582b8dc5e6\r\n",
        "callsid":"TJSceeec256-b343-4d13-bf26-febd73fcd484",
        "twilio":{}
}}
```

So the `payload.sdp` attribute is definitely NOT Json, but it doesn't really look like it's even trying to be, so it's not some kinda typo.

The entire body of the request is properly formed JSON though, renders and pretty print.

So what do I need to do to start an outgoing call with the Twilio 1.4 JavaScript SDK? About a month ago the dev working on this was making calls successfully, so it's definitely possible, but I'm not sure what changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm getting the same error. Changing

```
Twilio.Device.connect();
```

to

```
Twilio.Device.connect({x:null});
```

helped me to get outgoing calls working.

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicate and Lucas -- This is not expected behavior! This was introduced in 1.4.30. We've rolled back to 1.4.29, so if you're using the CDN this should automatically be resolved. If you're using npm, you can temporarily pin to 1.4.29. Once this is patched up server-side we will re-pin 1.4 to 1.4.30.

Comment: As of this morning, 1.4.30 is re-pinned on our CDN, and should now be safe to use on NPM.

Comment: @rrowland Is it possible to use the client recorder library mentioned here via a versioned package on something like NPM? AllI can find is your node npm package. Thanks!